# How to log only from my process onto a single log file

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have 3 different process running and wanted to collect logs from them on to a single log file, using logcat.

Is it possible this logfile to have logs only from my 3 processes ? How to do the same programitcally.

any help regarding the same highly appreciated.

-regards,
Manju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way call this method and put put your message what you write in  log file and is stored in your sd card.   Any where your application tested it will create a log and you can see the details

```
 public static void MyLog(String msg_location, String log_message) {

            String messgae_location = msg_location;
            String message_details = log_message;

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/mydata/LOG");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            BufferedWriter bufferedWritter = null;
            try {
                bufferedWritter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dir
                        + File.separator + "my_Log.txt", true));
                String logString = null;

                logString = currentDateTime1() + ": " + messgae_location + ":  "
                        + message_details + "\n";

                bufferedWritter.write(logString);
                bufferedWritter.newLine();
                bufferedWritter.flush();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the logcat output by tags.

You can use regular expressions when filtering. E.g. if you have 3 tags tag1m tag2, tag3 then if your filter is tag1|tag2 you will see logcaat output tagged by tag1 and tag2 (but not tag3).

To log your messages in a file better use [Log4j for android](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). It's also simple.